# Bootstrap modal stopped working in Chrome / Firefox but ok in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I have just recently noticed my bootstrap modals have stopped working when I hadn't changed anything. I've searched here and Google and no one has the same issue exactly. To prove my point I copied the Bootstrap demo code into a file and it proves not to work in Chrome or Firefox but does in IE8. I'm writing in asp.net 4, .aspx files using Microsoft VWD2010express.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div id="example">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            body here
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the above code is from here -> http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

under Modal

versions of browser are IE8:8.0.7601. Chrome: 31.0.1650.57 m. Firefox: 23.0.1

Comment: I should add in chrome / Firefox I just get a faded black background nothing else. In Ie I get a faded black background and the modal box with close / save buttons.

Comment: Seems to work for me on Chrome 31, OSX 10.8.5: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/LCTSj/

Comment: Thanks, I have just been trying jsfiddler too and even after copying your fiddler (which does work in chrome) I can't get it to work, any chance you could have a look at my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3afRT/

Comment: Ok, big thanks to Joshua Dwire, I have tried linking directly to the CDN's off Bootstrap and my modal is now working in Bootstrap. Tried the links under Bootstrap CDN here -> http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/. many thanks